# Redirect querystring with ? in it using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a URL format of

http://www.domain.com/?text

For any instance of this URL I'd like to redirect to a 3rd party URL but can't figure out how to match the supposed querystring.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/text(.*)$
RewriteRule http://www.google.com [R=301,L]
```

Doesn't work

Comment: Do you want "text" included in the redirect? A few examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt is fairly close. Add `/?` in target to strip off this query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/qipco
RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Doesn't seems to work at http://championsofracing.jfd-test.co.uk/index.php?/qipco

Comment: Perfect! THanks very much !